# Getting nil while matching the correct regex for the URL with a backlash and parameters Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I'm testing a regex that allows me to validate whether or not the current string matches the url https:// or http:// http://it_tv.sharepoint.com. Its working to the extent that it does check if the url matches when I do https://it_tv.sharepoint.com. What I would like to happen, is the ability to include http://it_tv.sharepoint.com/resources..../22 in that sense. I need it to be considered valid when the url has a resource or extension attached to it. http://it_tv.sharepoint.com/resources should match true as well. Is there a way to add a wild card for the / portion of the regex expression?

url_validator.rb

```
if "https://it_tv.sharepoint.com/".match(%r{^(http[s]?://|)(www.)?it_tv.sharepoint.com($|/$)})
 # => returns true

if "https://it_tv.sharepoint.com/resource/1005".match(%r{^(http[s]?://|)(www.)?it_tv.sharepoint.com($|/$)})
 # => returns false/nil
```

Comment: Do you mean to match anything after the `it_tv.sharepoint.com`? Or a sequence of `/` and 1+ chars other than `/`? Try `.match(%r{\A(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?it_tv\.sharepoint\.com(?:/[^/]+)*/?\z})`

Comment: Yea anything after the backlash should be alright. I can't really tell what by written after it. since its sharepoint.

Comment: Then you may even use `\A(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?it_tv\.sharepoint\.com(?:/.*)?\z`

Comment: Perfect. i think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
%r{\A(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?it_tv\.sharepoint\.com(?:/.*)?\z}
```

See the [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/uCkPHlgBmwKFB0)

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:https?://)?` - an optional substring, `https://` or `http://`
- `(?:www\.)?` - an optional `www.` substring
- `it_tv\.sharepoint\.com` - an `it_tv.sharepoint.com` substring
- `(?:/.*)?` - an optional `/` followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, char sequence
- `\z` - end of string.

If you want to require at least one non-`/` char between `/`s, you may use

```
%r{\A(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?it_tv\.sharepoint\.com(?:/[^/]+)*/?\z}
```

where `(?:/[^/]+)*/?` matches 0 or more occurrences of `/` and then 1+ chars other than `/`, and then an optional `/` (that is at the end of the string).

Comment: works perfectly. This is certainly, the correct answer .